# Failing a review audit due to lack of nuanced responses

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits

First off, this is my first failed audit, so I'm not sure how much I should care about this.

I was presented: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26052566 as an audit, which suggested that the question was closed as *'primarily opinion based'*. I didn't agree with that, but thought the question had other serious problems: it's basically a lump of code and an error log, without any expected behaviour/results - which made it *'unsuitable for the site in its current state'*, so that was the option I selected.

There's no option as far as I can see to say "This close reason isn't right, but the question should still be closed". What's a good action to take in this situation?

Comment: I kinda disagree: the question is kinda obvious: the OP wonders why he gets a type error that basically says "Not X, should be X". And the comments and the answer there imply that the domain experts found something worth looking at.

Comment: @gnat - Yep, that's the same situation, thanks. Basically the question chosen isn't really suitable for use as an audit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is closed for the "wrong" reason, the appropriate course of action is to choose "leave closed". It is not worth reopening a question just to re-close it. Too much effort wasted and potential for error; for very little, if any, gain.

If the question is improved so it can be reopened, yay! Otherwise, forget about it.

I you believe the close reason is misleading and want to help the asker to improve the question, **comment on how to improve the question specifically**. That might help the asker.

Regarding failing an audit, if it doesn't happen you with any frequency, you shouldn't worry at all. We all err, occasionally.

(Mind you, "leave closed" is what made you fail the audit, but the way you pose this question you seem to be worried more about the reopening/closure than about failing the audit, which is perfectly fine).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I was more concerned with failing what felt like an 'un-passable' audit - but as long as there's no real consequences, that's no big deal. But still, in the case where this was a legit review, the option to 'Concur with close, but for a different reason' would be handy.

Comment: Good. "Closing for a different reason" is not useful. It wouldn't give feedback to anyone. If you want to to give feedback, comments are the right tool. Re: failing audits, it only has consequences if it happens with some frequency. A single failure is no big deal.

Answer (score -1):

If you think you are looking at a question closed for "the wrong reason", and you really care: then take the time to leave a comment for the OP of that question. Explain to them what you think the *real* problem is, and what would be necessary to improve the question.

Beyond that, vote "leave closed" and move on.